# Can't change Workgroup/Domain due to netid.dll error

Tags: domain, workgroup, windows

I tried to re-add a restored VM to  AD-domain to restore the trust relationship. However, I cannot change the workgroup/domain *via Computer > Properties*. There's an error message which says that **C:\Windows\system32\netid.dll** is broken and the "Computername" tab is not present in System Settings.

I ran **SFC** and it says the file is corrupt but can't repair it, and I didn't manage to replace it manually due to insufficient permissions. Using **WMIC** and "JoinDomainOrWorkgroup" also didn't work.

Is there any other way to fix this DLL / change the workgroup/domain membership / re-add the computer to the domain or restore the trust relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was now able to gain access to the DLL and replace with one from another machine with an equivalent operating system using these commands:

```
takeown /f C:\Windows\System32\netid.dll
cacls C:\Windows\System32\netid.dll /G Administrator:F
```

> *Source:*
>
> *http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-delete-a-system-file-in-windows-vista/*

It's working now.